# Login to website with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to login to this [web site](https://www.google.it/portaleTitolari/titolari.html) with Python Selenium, for which I have written this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Mps(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.it/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_mps(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/portaleTitolari/titolari.html")
        driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen30").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen30").send_keys("username33")
        driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen11").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen11").send_keys("password33")
        driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen38").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is username and password input field name changes every time. How can I locate username, password input field, and login button in this situation?

Comment: By "change name" do you mean that the `id` attribute changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those input fields seem to have static classes. Simply search for an input element with the given class using xpath. Something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='login_component_input']")
```

Since the password uses the same class, you might try including the element type in the query:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='login_component_input' and @type='password']")
```

xpath is a very expressive language. You should take some time to understand it if you're going to be automating websites.

Comment: work for the first input, login .. bat not work for password

Comment: @kingcope: did you use the proper class for the password? It's different, of course.

Comment: how i can locate password input ?

Comment: Look at the page source. This is a very basic skill you're going to need if you're trying to automate a website.

Comment: I am newbie with selenium

Comment: username and password have same class

Comment: @kingcope: Since the password has a different type, you can include that in your xpath. I've updated my answer.